# SFMC Content Builder: Use reference content inside dynamic content - No Code solution

Tags: marketing-cloud, dynamic-content

Issue: Users create content blocks for use in dynamic content wizard. When user edits content, user must relink in dynamic content wizard, in order for edits to appear in messages.

Question: Is it possible to use the wizard, but insert content as reference block?

Workaround: Create content block, then create reference block that includes content block, and use the reference block inside dynamic content. BUT seems like a lot of extra steps (and double the content blocks).  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reference content feature that works with Dynamic content blocks yet, unfortunately it only works with static content.

The workaround is what you mentioned of creating a reference block with the dynamic content inside Or using AMPScript with one of the content block by name/id/key function and defining your rules using IF statements.
[Content Block By Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/contentblockbyname.htm)